# wallpaper change

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7

I am looking for the correct API to change the windows 7 starter edition wallpaper

microsoft has done something to avoid having the windows background wallpaper changed

Comment: It's strange to speak about the "correct" API to do something that's denied. The "correct" way to do it is not to do it :)

Comment: @himself - many programs/functions would not be available today if we would follow Microsoft's advice ad-litteram.

Comment: @plastkort - see my solution here: https://superuser.com/a/1249967/38821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, one of the limitations of Windows 7 Starter is that it cannot change the background; essentially there is no Microsoft/Windows API.

I did find a discussion at StackExchange/SuperUser discussing this. I would repost parts of it, but it's long. What I got out of it is--either do a registry hack and a permissions change (not viable for program distribution) or run a third party app over the windows display.

[Source 1](https://superuser.com/questions/69601/how-to-change-the-wallpaper-in-windows-7-starter-edition)

[Source 2](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16041/change-the-wallpaper-and-customization-settings-in-windows-7-starter-edition/)